# Submitting HTML form to MySQL with Node.js -- undefined values

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am using Node.js, Express, EJS templating and MySQL for a website. I am trying to submit a form to a MySQL database, the routing seems to be working fine, but all the values inserted into the table are undefined.

From contact.ejs:

```
...

<form action="form-sub" method="POST">
        <label for="cName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cName" name="cName" required> <br/>
        <label for="cEmail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="cEmail" name="cEmail" required><br/>
        <p>Which package is your query about?</p> <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="ans1" name="answers" value="Standard">
        <label for="ans1">Standard</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" id="ans2" name="answers" value="Chosen">
        <label for="ans2">The Chosen One Package</label> <br/>
        <p>We may respond via an owl, on a scale of 1-10, how scared are you of owls?</p><br/>
        <p>(10 is the most scared)</p><br/>
        <input type="number" id="numOwl" name="numOwl" required><br/>
        <label for="query">Please enter your query:</label><br/>
        <input type="textarea" id="query" name="query" required><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="subBtn" name="subBtn" value="Submit">
      </form>
...
```

From server.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const myDB = require('./database');

let port = 5000;

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static.join(__dirname,'public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Add routing to several endpoints

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.render('index');
});

app.get("/houses", (req,res) => {
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.render('houses');
});

app.get("/contact", (req,res) => {
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.render('contact');
});

app.get("/form-sent", (req,res) => {
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.render('form-sent');
})

app.get('*',(req,res) => {
    res.status(404);
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.render('404');
})

app.post("/form-sub", (req,res) => {
    let query = `INSERT INTO form_data (name, email, package, scared, comments) VALUES ("${req.body.cName}", "${req.body.cEmail}", "${req.body.answers}", "${req.body.numOwl}", "${req.body.comments}")`;
    
    myDB.query(query, (err,result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Record inserted!");
        res.redirect("/form-sent");
    })
});

app.listen(port, () => {console.log('Server has started!')});
```

As I mentioned, an entry is indeed happening to my database table, but the elements are all undefined. Do you see anything that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **WARNING**: You **must** use [placeholder values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries) to avoid nasty SQL injection issues. Do not use template strings to inject data.

Comment: Worth dumping out `console.log(req.body)` to be sure what you're getting is correct.

Comment: Tip: It's also worth embracing `async`/`await` to avoid "nesting hell" caused by having to put callback functions inside of callback function inside of... There are also higher-level [SQL libraries](http://sequelizejs.com) that can help manage this workload.

Comment: @tadman I've seen others mention placeholders values too, I will fix it, thank you! 
I also logged out the body, first undefined, changed the port and it started working? I had a similar problem with routing, one page wouldn't load at one port, and would normally do at another. 
Anyways, thank you!

Comment: @tadman Oh I didn't know that, thank you so much, will check it out now!

Comment: Don't forget that when you make a change to a Node application you need to stop and start the process to pick up the changes. Simply reloading is not an option unless you have a process monitor that does that for you, often called a "live reload" tool. There's some that incorporate "hot reloading" too, so CSS changes can be reflected in the browser as you work.

Comment: Yes, doing this already, stopping and starting Node again. Might be worth checking "live reload" though. Seriously, appreciate all those tips :)